# How to configure search in Elasticsearch/PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I have a products table

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  description TEXT NULL,
  price BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

How to make so that when adding/editing PostgreSQL's data is automatically updated in Elasticsearch?

Comment: You can use elasticsearch foreign data wrapper based on multicorn library. But there is one gotcha - elasticsearch up to 2.4 does not have transactions (ES 5.x seems to have translog) therefore in older ES you cannot be sure which data where inserted and which not. We have such a solution running with pg 9.6 and ES 2.4 so we have to repeat insertion into ES with `select except select` from ES to make sure we insert only missing data.